# Case sensitive check for query parameter?

Tags: javascript

How do I add in a check in my code to make the parameter variable not case sensitive? I want a user to be able to type in ab=ac as a query parameter or AB=AC or aB=aC and any other variations. My code is below. Based on the parameter present, headOne or headTwo will show on the page.

```
 myObject: function() {
    var parameter = window.location.search.includes("ab=ac");
    var headOne = data.headerOne;
    var headTwo = data.headerTwo;
    var helpers = _.extend(this.constructor.__super__.myObject.call(this), {
        header: parameter ? headerOne : headerTwo
    });
    return helpers;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can convert it to lowercase and compare:

```
var parameter = window.location.search.toLowerCase().includes("ab=ac");
//------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize it would be that simple